# How to handle CLion inspections and config files?

Tags: clion

I'm making a firmware for an embedded device and when I build for different hardware I use different config settings.

For this I have a config file `config.h`:

```
#define FOO_MODE 7
```

In my code I would then use something like

```
void do_something_if_in_mode_4() {
  if (FOO_MODE == 4)
    return;
  // ...
}
```

But CLion understands the config file as code and tells me that the "Condition is always false" and that `return` is unreachable code.

Answer (score 0):

That file *is* code! The preprocessor included that file's content in your main source code and replaced all occurrences of FOO_MODE with 4. The compiler never sees FOO_MODE; remember that the preprocessor is dumb string handling that happens completely before the compiler gets to see the source code

And your compiler correctly detects the unreachable code, because 7 is not 4. The compiler will also be smart enough to omit the unreachable code in the binary, which is desirable.

If the warning annoys you, I'm sure there's ways to disable it. However, I think it's a good tool, so I'd keep it.

For code that you really do not even want to compile for some devices, try to use preprocessor `#if` instead, to effectively remove the text from the code that the compiler gets to see.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to keep the warning on in general, but I'd like to tell CLion that there might be different values for `FOO_MODE`, just not right now in this configuration.

Comment: That's not possible. As said, it's the compiler or language server that gives you these warnings, and because the preprocessor runs before they analyze the code, they never see FOO_MODE.